# Problem with most recently used in RUN command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-xp

In Windows XP, when I enter some path or process name in 'Run'(Start->Run) i had to enter the full path/name.

For example consider the path,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\MEDIA or excel or notepad etc
```

which I open very often. Previously once I enter "C:\ or ex, or no..", I would get the recently used lists and I can easily choose, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\MEDIA etc" from the list. But recently I cleared all my temp,recent files and all such stuffs. After this process, even after entering the full path, the first time, the same is required on second and third attempts. I'm not getting the recently used stuffs.

Why is the "recently used" not popping up .? Where is this information stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Check

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

did you set `ClearRecentDocsOnExit`?

2-MRU Run is set on:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

You can see a,b,c,d,e,f,g...

Comment: I checked the first point. "ClearRecentDocsOnExit" is not on. Actually I manually cleared all items like Clearing Recent History in IE and firefox and all other places like 'Temp' etc.

Comment: There are no keys under the location, "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU". Just a 'Default' key is present

Comment: 1/did you have any 'privacy' program installed? 2/if you installed tweakUi, check if "Clear document history" on exit in the Explorer section is there.

Comment: I just installed TweakUI and found "Clear document history" is NOT checked. :( Any other suggestions please.